# Using a passed by reference struct variable in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a basic pointer question.
I have some code like this:
Please let me know if anything is wrong in the following code:

```
struct abc {
  int a;
  int b;
};

void func2(int*); // defined elsewhere

void func1 (struct abc *p1)
{
  struct abc var1 = *p1; // ======> Can I do this ? 

  func2(&var1.b);
  func2(&p1->b);      // =========> Which of these 2 is right ? 
}
```

Comment: what is the signature of `func2()`?

Comment: func2(int *) is the signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `struct abc var1 = *p1;` ======> Can I do this ?

Yes, this copies the struct pointed by p1 in the local variable var1.

> `func2(&var1.b);`
>   `func2(&p1->b);`      =========> Which of these 2 is right ?

Both, if `func2()` accepts a `int*` as parameter. It depends if you want `func2` to modify `p1->b` or `var1.b`.